# PHP regex - removing chars after

Tags: php, regex

I have PHP strings like

```
$str1 = "hello ... this is the rest of the line"
```

or

```
$str1 = "ASDFDF ... this is also the rest of the line";
```

I am trying to right a regex statement that will extract the text after "..." appears in the string. I am not able to do this reliably..

so in the above cases, i want to...

> ```
>  $extract = "this is the rest of the line";
> ```

... you get the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

Using strpos and substr:

```
function rest_of_line($line){
  $loc = strpos($line, '...');
  if($loc !== FALSE){
      return substr($line, $loc+3);
  }
  return $line;
}

$str1 = "hello ... this is the rest of the line";
$str2 = "ASDFDF ... this is also the rest of the line";
echo rest_of_line($str1);
echo rest_of_line($str2);
```

Or using explode:

```
$rest = explode('...', $str1, 2); // the 2 ensures that only the first occurrence of ... actually matters.
echo $rest[1]; // you should probably check whether there actually was a match or not
```

Comment: That's a rather complicated way to do this.

Comment: @Jon - Seems simple to me... The complexity is in the error checking for the function, which is unnecessary if the OP is certain that the delimiter is present (which is the exact same assumption you and this answer make when you use explode).

Comment: @nickb Exactly. The first approach will just return the line if it does not contain `...`. Thus it's kinda fool-proof ;).

Answer (score 3):

Why use regex? Just explode the string and pick up the second element in the result:

```
$str = "hello ... this is the rest of the line";
list(, $rest) = explode(" ... ", $str, 2) + array(, '');
```

It's basically the same thing, and the regex for this is no faster.

Comment: php argument order strikes again: delimiter needs to go first with explode ;).

Comment: @hakre I don't think its cool to edit Jon's code like this without his consent. That's more than just a 'fixed your formatting' and if it were my code I would not be too happy about your edit.

Comment: Yes, I know about this. However, better is sometimes not objective but in the eye of the beholder. Here, the same effect could be achieved using an if statement.

Comment: @middus While I agree that an edit like this is a little bit much, I do not disagree with the edit made. Thanks for pseudo-moderating, though.

Answer (score 0):

`explode` it at `...`

it's a great function :)